# Oracle DB, concat all values from 1 column using "," separator

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, string-aggregation

I have Oracle DB table with 1 column `UUID`

[image]

How can I concatenate all the `UUID` values in one string separated by `","` so the output will be like

```
"id1","id2","id3","id4"....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(uuid, ',') within group(order by uuid) uuids
from mytable
```

This will give you a single record with a single column containing all `uuid`s, separated with a comma.

Note that `listagg()` returns a `varchar`, hence the output cannot be more than 4000 bytes.

Also note that:

- the comma is the default separator, so in your case it is not strictly necessary to pass a second argument to the function
- I added an `order by` clause in order to generate a deterministic result: this option is not mandatory, so if the ordering of items in the list does not matter to you then you can leave it apart (in which case you will get the `uuid`s in an undefined order)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listagg()` -- assuming there are not too many values.  The maximum string size is 4000 bytes.

```
selest '"' || listagg(uuid, '","') within group (order by uuid) || '"'
```